# Python API for Amazon Simple Email Service

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I've made the API for Amazon SES: http://tagmask.com/vladimir/posts/26
It is my first experience in creating an API for such serious service. 
I want to make it useful for people, so my main question is what best practices to creating such API?

Comment: Once you get some feedback on best practices, you can get feedback on the code itself at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I would suggest looking at how the boto python project has coded python bindings for AWS APIs. They do a good job and I learned from reading that code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this wont be a REST API or service, rather a wrapper for the new Amazon SES.

For a RESTful service, i'd defer you to [REST guidelines](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/08/11/rest.html)
As for generic API design, there's a good start [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~NatProg/apiusability.html). There are several PDF's available worth a read.